# How to iterate through a nodeList functional style

Tags: javascript, prototype

I frequently want to iterate through a NodeList with forEach or map. My simplified code works like this:

```
var nodeListMap = Array.prototype.map;
var els = document.querySelectorAll('.classname');
nodeListMap.call(els, function(el){...});
```

This works fine. However, I'd prefer not have to `map.call`, but if I do this...

```
var nodeListMap = Array.prototype.map.call;
var els = document.querySelectorAll('.classname');
nodeListMap(els, function(el){...});
```

Then it returns

```
TypeError: object is not a function
```

How can I modify the code so I simply do `nodeListMap(array, fn)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After six years the `map` and `forEach` methods are available on NodeLists on most browsers (the odd duck being IE usual). Check `forEach` nodeList [support on caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-api_nodelist_foreach).

If older browser support is needed, I have settled on the following for brevity and clarity (ES6+):

`const els = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.selector'));`

Then, you can simply iterate as...

`els.forEach(el => doSomething)`

Comment: Wow, I wish this much thought went into more decisions. This was going to be suggested solution, too.

Comment: This isn't actually an answer to the question you asked, and has the overhead of creating a completely new array, even though it's possible to use the "functional" `.map` and `.forEach` functions directly on a `NodeList`.

Comment: @Alnitak addressed some of your feedback.

Answer (score 9):

I've encountered the same question and my super simple solution with ES6 is:

```
const els = [...document.querySelectorAll('.classname')]
```

Such way nodeList becomes a regular Array and you can use `map`, `reduce` and so on.

Comment: @Bergi I prefer the given answer.  It's not a particularly arcane feature.  This is exactly what it's purpose is.

Answer (score 3):

`Array.prototype.map.call` just gets you the `call` function (`Function.prototype.call`), without the context. You will need to bind it to the `map` function:

```
var nodeListMap = Function.prototype.call.bind(Array.prototype.map);
```

If you don't want to use `bind`, you could also write

```
function nodeListMap(_list /* … */) {
    return Function.prototype.call.apply(Array.prototype.map, arguments);
}
```

Comment: There have to be side-effects to doing this.

Comment: @Shmiddty: What do you mean by "side-effects"? Of course JS is not a pure functional language and allows side effects.

Comment: @bergi he appears to be suggesting that it will break something

Comment: I don't think @Shmiddty means "side-effects" in that sense. As far as `Function.prototype.call.bind(Array.prototype.map);` goes, it doesn't affect other parts of the program. It's not modifying `Array.prototype` or anything like that. It's just as awesome and convoluted as it reads.

Comment: that use of `.call.apply` is _evil_ ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to add this functionality to the prototype NodeList:

```
NodeList.prototype.map = function(step){
    return Array.prototype.map.call(this, step);
};
NodeList.prototype.forEach = function(step){
    return Array.prototype.forEach.call(this, step);
};
```

With this, you could just call:

```
els.map(function(el){...});
```

It should be noted that some people would likely frown upon modifying the prototype of NodeList in this way, but I don't really see a problem with it personally.

Or, if you need to set the `this` object:

```
NodeList.prototype.map = function(step){
    return Array.prototype.map.call(this, step, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
};
NodeList.prototype.forEach = function(step){
    return Array.prototype.forEach.call(this, step, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
};
```

**Note:** the above has a side effect that when you don't pass a second parameter, `this` becomes an empty array instead of `window`.

or

```
NodeList.prototype.map = Array.prototype.map;
NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
```

Comment: That would prevent us from using the second argument of those functions. Why not just `NodeList.prototype.map = Array.prototype.map;`?

Comment: @Bergi ISTR that some browsers (older IE?) don't allow you to modify the prototype of builtin types.  Not that older IE actually _has_ `map()`

Answer (score 2):

It's probably simplest just to write your own function that "does the right thing"

```
function map() {
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 0);
    var ctx = args.shift();
    return [].map.apply(ctx, args);
}
```

which will then work for *any* pseudo-array object.

**EDIT** this code is updated to ensure that *all* arguments are passed to `.map`, even if ECMA add more in the future.

Comment: You probably want `Array` instead of `[]`

Comment: I did have `[].prototype.map` which was of course wrong, and should have been `Array.prototype.map`, but `[].map` on its own works just as well.

Comment: @Bergi I was fixing that as you typed.  Shmiddty's answer has (had) the same problem.

Comment: Thanks, this turned out to be the fastest solution and I like that I can use it on things other than nodeLists http://jsperf.com/nodelistmap